# Java - escaping double quotes in string from file

Tags: java, regex

I have html string from file. I need to escape all double quotes. So I do this way:

```
String content=readFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
content=content.replaceAll("\"","\\\"");
System.out.println(content);
```

However, the double quotes are not escaped and the string is the same as it was before replaceAll method. When I do

```
String content=readFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
content=content.replaceAll("\"","^^^");
System.out.println(content);
```

All double quotes are replaced with ^^^.

Why `content.replaceAll("\"","\\\"");` doesn't work?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361971/replace-all-double-quotes-within-string?rq=1

Comment: @LucasPottersky: I think that question is a more generic one. This one focuses on the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use 4 backslashes to denote one literal backslash in the replacement pattern:

```
content=content.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");
```

Here, `\\\\` means a literal `\` and `\"` means a literal `"`.

More details at [Java `String#replaceAll` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see [Matcher.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String))

And later in [`Matcher.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)) documentation:

> Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string.

Another fun replacement is [replacing quotes with dollar sign](http://ideone.com/Wjcojs): the replacement is `"\\$"`. The 2 `\`s turn into 1 literal `\` for the regex engine and it escapes the special character `$` used to define backreferences. So, now it is a literal inside the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do :

```
String content = "some content with \" quotes.";
content = content.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

Why will this work?

`\"` represents the `"` symbol, while you need `\"`.

If you add a `\` as a prefix (`\\"`) then you'll have to escape the prefix too, i.e. you'll have a `\\\"`. This will now represent `\"`, where `\` is not the escaping character, but the symbol `\`.

However in the Java String the `"` character will be escaped with a `\` and you will have to replace it as well. Therefore prefixing again with `\\` will do fine:

```
x = x.replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

Answer (score 3):

Much easier with [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/)-

```
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("\""));
```

Output:

```
\"
```

Answer (score 2):

It took me way too long in Java to discover `Pattern.quote` and `Matcher.quoteReplacement`.  These will you achieve what you are trying to do here - which is a simple "find" and "replace" - without any regex and escape logic. The `Pattern.quote` here would not be necessary but it shows how you can ensure that the "find" part is not interpreted as a regex string:

```
@Test
public void testEscapeQuotes()
{
    String content="some content with \"quotes\".";
    content=content.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\""), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\""));
    Assert.assertEquals("some content with \\\"quotes\\\".", content);
}
```

Remember that you can also use the simple `.replace` method which will also "replaceAll" but will not interpret your parameters as regular expressions:

```
@Test
public void testEscapeQuotes()
{
    String content="some content with \"quotes\".";
    content=content.replace("\"", "\\\"");
    Assert.assertEquals("some content with \\\"quotes\\\".", content);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I am surprised by the behaviour, but it seems like you need to double-escape the backslash:

```
System.out.println("\"Hello world\"".replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\""));
```

which outputs:

```
\"Hello world\"
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/5t6XQ5)