# Retrieving a Firebase String array to an Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to convert a String array from Firebase to an actual array but it comes as a single string from Firebase.

To clarify it, this is what I have on Firebase:

[image: date_image]

And I am trying to retrieve those Dates and Convert them to an Array, as they become a single string which makes it very difficult to separate into different dates.

I have tried to replace the quotation of the string as indicated[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361971/replace-all-double-quotes-within-string), hoping to get the square brackets only and use that a array, since I'll be having an array[], which I succeeded in doing but converting the array to list shows double square brackets as seen below.

> 06-22 13:35:18.241 10352-10352/com.angelserve.zacktinga.angelserv I/System.out: LIST ARRAY: [[Sat Jun 30 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, Sat Jun 30 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, Sun Jul 01 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, Mon Jul 02 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, Tue Jul 03 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, Wed Jul 04 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, Thu Jul 05 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, Fri Jul 06 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018, Sat Jul 07 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018]]

I am getting the dates a DataSnapshot from firebase like below:

```
mCurrentUserRefDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            System.out.println("DATE LIST: " + dataSnapshot.child("requested_dates").getValue());

            dates.replace("\"", "");

            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(dates);
            System.out.println("LIST ARRAY: " + list);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

What I need as a solution is a way to convert my firebase datasnapshot of

> requested_dates

and convert them into a working array.

This is my JSON Firebase datasnapshot:
[image]

Comment: Please add a more detailed json / screenshot of your database.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I've just edited it now and included the detailed json of the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, I recommend you to use the following steps. First you need to get the value of the `requested_dates` property like this:

```
String string = dataSnapshot.child("requested_dates").getValue(String.class);
```

Assuming that you have a `[` at the beginning of the String and a `]` at the end of the String, let's replace both symbols with an empty String. Then we need split it using a comma and a space `,`. The result will be an array of strings.

```
String[] parts = string.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(", ");
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    Log.d("TAG", parts[i]);
}
```

The output in your console will be:

```
Wed Jun 13 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018
//and so on
```